# Implicit conversions in scala within a class, why and why not?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

So implicit conversions can be pretty confusing, namely because of the 3 ways to do it, and the way it handles scope, the idea with this question is to clear up some misunderstandings, like many that I had.

**Reference:**

```scala
class Demo {
  def test(in:Option[Int] = None) {
     println(in.getOrElse(0))
  }
}
```

Simply put an implicit conversion will try to convert from type `A` to type `B` if type `A` is not accepted in the function in which you are passing it, but type `B` is.

```scala
val d = new Demo
d.test()        //prints 0
d.test(Some(2)) //prints 2
d.test(3)       //should print 3
//but will only if you import the following 
//into the scope where the function is CALLED
implicit def intToOption(in:Int):Option[Int] = Some(in)
```

**Scope**
There are already many links that discuss the scope in detail, but the biggest misconception I had was that I thought you could define an implicit conversion within a class and then on the usage side of the class, the programmer could for example pass type `A` into a function and it will implicitly convert it to `B` **for that class only**.

Like this:

```scala
class Demo {
  implicit def intToOption(in:Int):Option[Int] = Some(in)

  def test(in:Option[Int] = None) {
     println(in.getOrElse(0))
  }
}


val d = new Demo
d.test()        //prints 0
d.test(Some(2)) //prints 2
d.test(3)       //should print 3 without any imports or implicit definitions
```

This has a lot of value, in that it stops dumb `Some(whatever)` wrapped variables, and sticks with scala best practices in using `Option` instead of null.

But no dice, you have to explicitly define or import the conversion into the scope where you call the function, and this leads to the army of naysayers which are valid in saying that you should avoid it because it can cause some weird bugs and strange debugging. And makes implicits kind of limited since I believe defining a conversion for a specific class will be much more useful for the user for the class, and more concise, and aid scalas best practices.

So why Doesn't scala do this? Or more specifically why shouldn't scala do this?

And what other misconceptions or common errors have you discovered or dealt with scalas implicits?

Comment: Biggest misconception about implicit conversions in Scala: that you should be using them for anything except enrichment via `implicit class`.

Comment: @TravisBrown could you explain a little more? 
basically dumb it down.

Comment: Sorry—can't go into detail at the moment, but the problems you might solve with an implicit conversion are almost always better handled with a type class.

Comment: @TravisBrown I, too, would love a good reference on this topic!

Comment: @TravisBrown I had a look at type classes but I'm having difficulty getting it to replicate the functionality I mentioned without added more overhead to the "user" of the function